# Find unknown side in triangle

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

I encountered this problem which I am not sure how to solve.

Length of two sides are given as **250 ft and 60 ft**.These sides are **adjacent** to each other.Measurement of one of the angles of triangle is given as **50 degrees**.
The angle is enclosed between side having length **60 ft** and the side whose length needs to be found.

Below is the pic of problem.

Find x in this image [image]

Comment: **Hint:** law of cosines

Comment: Thanks andrei.I used law of cosines and found x to be 284.305 ft.But when I drilled down further to find the remaining angles using sine law, angles came to be 60 degrees and 10 degrees.The sum of all these angles don't add to 180 degrees.

Comment: If sin(x)=sin(60), does that automatically mean x=60?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis thanks . I got your point.x can be 120 degrees too

Comment: @Andrei got the point.thanks

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Let  $ a,b,c $ be respectively the opposite sides of the angles $ A,B,C $ of the triangle.

then we have an interesting identity

$$\frac{a}{\sin(A)} = \frac{b}{\sin(B)} = \frac{c}{\sin(C)}$$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Let $|BC|=a=60$,
$|AC|=b=250$, $|AB|=x$,
$\angle ABC=\beta=50^\circ$.

Draw a perpendicular $CD\perp AB$. Then

\begin{align}
|AB|=x&=|AD|+|BD|=x_1+x_2
.
\end{align}

\begin{align} 
\triangle CDB:\quad
x_2&=a\cos\beta
,\\
|CD|=h&=a\sin\beta
,\\
\triangle CAD:\quad
x_1&=
\sqrt{b^2-h^2}
=
\sqrt{b^2-a^2\sin^2\beta}
,\\
x=x_2+x_1
&=
a\cos\beta
+\sqrt{b^2-a^2\sin^2\beta}
\\
&=
60\cos50^\circ
+\sqrt{250^2-60^2\sin^2 50^\circ}
\\
&\approx 284.3
.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is cosine rule, as you need one side and its opposite angle to use the sine law easily.

Cosine rule is not entirely trivial here, it leads to a quadratic, but at least it's smooth sailing.

The choice of what goes on the $\mathrm{LHS}$ is dependent on what angle you're given. Here the angle is $50^{\circ}$ so $250$ (opposite the given angle) goes on the $\mathrm{LHS}$.

$250^2 = x^2 + 60^2 - 2(x)(60)\cos 50^{\circ}$

$x^2 - 120\cos 50^{\circ} x -58900 = 0$

Solving that (using quadratic formula) gives you:

$\displaystyle x = \frac{120\cos 50^{\circ} \pm \sqrt{(120\cos 50^{\circ})^2 - 4(-58900)}}{2}$

$x \approx 284.31$ or $x \approx -207.17$, and it's clear the negative root must be rejected.

So the answer is $x \approx 284.31$.